# Where is the CE certification on Apple Watch?

Tags: apple-watch

I've looked everywhere it seems, but I can't find any trace of any CE or FCC certification on the Apple Watch. Now I hear FCC has loosened up lately, but not CE. All electronics have to carry a CE symbol if sold within EU. So where is it?

Answer (score 5):

After scrutinising every angle of the Apple Watch I finally spotted the CE marking!

It is hidden on the inside of the slot that holds the wristband. See pict below. The etchings are not visible to the eye. The shot was taken with my iPhone X. Even using the x2 lens, I had to pinch zoom quite a lot  to get this picture.

[image]

I can only imagine this must have taken an army of certification experts to make it happen. Kudos to Apple for putting much effort into creating a clean product! It really throws some light on the amazing amount of work it takes to make something perfect.

Answer (score 3):

## Declarations of Conformity

Apple publish their [declarations of conformity](https://www.apple.com/euro/compliance/). These documents include the European standards that have been met:

- [Apple Watch Series 3 - Cellular (A1891)](https://www.apple.com/euro/compliance/pdf/A1891_EU_DoC.pdf)
- [Apple Watch Series 3 - Cellular (A1889)](https://www.apple.com/euro/compliance/pdf/A1889_EU_DoC.pdf)

### Exemptions to affixing the CE marking

[CE marking](https://europa.eu/youreurope/business/product/ce-mark/index_en.htm) does appear to required, but there [are exemptions](https://cemarking.net/affixing-ce-marking/) quoted below – thanks to [@PeterJ](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/83841/peterj) for find the exemptions link:

> Nevertheless, there are cases when affixing the CE marking on the product is impossible or not possible under reasonable technical or economic conditions. Furthermore, cases when the minimum dimensions cannot be respected, or it cannot be ensured that the CE marking is visibly, legibly and indelibly affixed (European Commission, 2013). In those cases, the CE marking can be affixed to the packaging, it is exists, and/or the accompanying documents. It is not allowed to affix the CE mark to the packing and/or accompanying documents for aesthetic reasons.

Comment: There are exemptions to marking the actual product possible if you wanted to add a reference from here to your answer: https://cemarking.net/affixing-ce-marking/

Comment: @PeterJ Thank you. I have updated the answer with your link.